# What are SELinux ".lst" files under /usr/share/selinux/targeted on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, files, selinux

I can see several ".lst" file under /usr/share/selinux/targeted on CentOS 7:

- base.lst
- modules-base.lst
- modules-contrib.lst
- nonbasemodules.lst

".lst" files contain a list of SELinux policy packages ("*.pp" files). 
What is the purpose of ".lst" files, why are they needed there?

Answer (score 1):

Those are used by `semodule` which is a tool used for managing SELinux policy modules.

Operations are basically installing/removing, upgrading or listing modules. You can also use `semodule` to force a reload of policy without performing any other transaction. `semodule` acts on module packages created by `semodule_package`. Conventionally, these files have a `.pp` suffix (policy package).

So policy modules are grouped on those lists then `SELinux` modularization will combine them when the system boots into the active policy. This policy is then loaded into memory. The combined binary version of this loaded policy can be found under `/etc/selinux/targeted/policy`